# How to manage Azure AD with service user and token instead of certificate?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions

How can I access and manage AAD groups via powershell when I only have an App-User and a token?

I don't like to manage the certificates especially since I want to use Azure functions to modify the AD.

Descriptions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/signing-in-service-principal?view=azureadps-2.0)
are great but they always use the cert to connect to the AD.

Is there a alternative that i could use to connect to the AAD and manage it automatically from powershell?

Comment: [Create the service principal with password instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps).

Comment: Well that was to obvious for me.... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can create the service principal with a specified name and password. https://xebia.com/blog/a-better-way-and-script-to-add-a-service-principal-in-azure-for-vsts/